# Fragment to Fragment communication (pager adapter)

Tags: android

Let me start by saying this I have tried every way to send data from a fragment to another and each time ive failed somehow.

I have a main activity with pager adapter and tabs and i have 5 fragments and I need to send data from fragment 5 to rest of them, I have tried interface and 3 other ways and I end up crashing or getting error on Start.

I used interface and it works only sometimes and in order to find why it doesnt work in some cases I have come here but haven't got any answers

Thank You in advance.

Main Activity:

```
   package com.redot.puzzle3;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.WindowManager;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Remove title bar
    //  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);





    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
     findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
  Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }


        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new Frag1();
            case 1:
                return new Frag2();
            case 2:
                return new Frag3();
            case 3:
                return new Frag4();
            case 4:
                return new Frag5();
            case 5:


            default:
            return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Inventory";
            case 1:
                return "3Men";
            case 2:
                return "Test";
            case 3:
                return "TheMan";
            case 4:
                return "King";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Main Activity Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout          
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.MainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragments' builds are similar

Fragments:

```
  public  class Frag1 extends Fragment  {


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, 
    container, false);

    return myInflatedView;

  }
```

**UPDATE**:

I used shared preferences utils and everything worked except i got this error when i go to the page where the data is sent

```
10-11 04:49:13.040 6734-6734/com.redot.puzzle3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.redot.puzzle3, PID: 6734
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.redot.puzzle3.SharedPreferenceUtils.getData1(SharedPreferenceUtils.java:30)
                                                                 at com.redot.puzzle3.Frag1.<init>(Frag1.java:19)
                                                                 at com.redot.puzzle3.MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(MainActivity.java:71)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:101)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1005)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1153)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:665)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:627)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:608)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2169)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

which refers to this method:

```
 public static int getData1(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getInt(DATA1, x);
}
```

Fragment 1 where i get the data :
         int Riddle=  SharedPreferenceUtils.getData1(getActivity());

I have only 1 data and thats int and I was searching for sharedprefences and i found alot of good stuff.

So this is what I am doing and it works  :

Fragment 5( the fragment that sends the data):

```
  Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences SU = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "Riddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= SU.edit();
    editor.putString("riddle",""+riddle);
    editor.commit();
```

Fragment 1( gets the data):

```
     Context context = getActivity();
         SharedPreferences SU = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "Riddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("riddle",""));
```

I had some problems with sending ints so i sent string and converted to int

Comment: To send data between Fragments, there are multiple ways to achieve this. 1. Implement through shared preference 2. Create a static variable to send the data (not recommended).

Comment: You should send data between two fragments using an interface. The data should be passed  by the activity. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Please provide error in logcat.

Comment: @king_abu1918 this happens when i use an interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638540/fragment-to-fragment-interface-and-transaction-replace/46670787#46670787

Comment: @ScottS i get  this stack trace when i use interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638540/fragment-to-fragment-interface-and-transaction-replace/46670787#46670787

Comment: Check my answer please.@amirsoltani

Comment: @KeLiuyue im checking your answer right now I got an error im working on it 1 sec i'll let you know how it went Thank you any ways man

Comment: @KeLiuyue I updated my post take a look. but thank you anyways mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` in your code .

Try this .

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

    private static final String SP_NAME = "sp";
    public static final String DATA1 = "data1";
    public static final String DATA2 = "data2";


    // create
    public static boolean createSP(Context context, String data1, String data2) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(DATA1, data1);
        editor.putString(DATA2, data2);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    // clear
    public static void clearSP(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
    }

    // get access info
    public static String getData1(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getString(DATA1, "");
    }
    // get branch info
    public static String getData2(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getString(DATA2, "");
    }
}
```

**Use in `Frag5`**

```
SharedPreferenceUtils.createSP(getActivity(),data1,data2);
```

**And use in other `Fragment`**

```
String data1 = SharedPreferenceUtils.getData1(getActivity());
String data2 = SharedPreferenceUtils.getData2(getActivity());
```

**Note**

- change data1 and data2 to the value you want
- change `getData1` and `getData2` to the method you want

Comment: Thank you man , 1 small issue tho im using PagerAdapter so it doesnt send the data right away it takes alittle bit of time ( i go from fragment 5 to 1 then it updates the data do you know any solution?

Comment: 1.I also use `EventBus` to update the data .2.Also if you want to update right now when the fragment is visible ,you can use `setUserVisibleHint` in fragment .

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have a lot of options to communicate with fragments. I want to suggest you [CachePot - Android Simple Data Cache](https://github.com/kimkevin/CachePot) for caching data.

First of all, push the data that you want to pass.

```
CachePot.getInstance().push(data);
```

Second pop your data from CachePot.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Data data = CachePot.getInstance().pop(Data.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer im looking into it

Comment: That's a great way, I'm new to android so i'm trying to learn other ways. But Thank you

Comment: @amirsoltani No problem! it's not correct answer, choose what you want! good luck!